# Are there more than Five kingdoms?

Tags: homework, classification

Is it true that scientists have disregarded their belief that there are five kingdoms and instead, they have theorized that there are multiple kingdoms?

Comment: What research have you done to find an answer?

Comment: Can you provide a source that led you to ask this question? If you do not provide more information and/or indication that you've researched this yourself, your question will likely be closed and not answered. Please take the time to improve your question. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) on our help page.

Answer (score 1):

Taxonomic classification is a large area of controversial debate. See for example [Cavalier-Smith's system of classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalier-Smith's_system_of_classification), they described eight kingdoms, then six, then 7 kingdoms in subsequent publications.
Other (older) theories describe 6 kingdoms, two prokaryotic (Eubacteria and Archeae) and four Eukaryotic (Protista, Plantae, Fungi, Animalia) [See image on Wikipedia's "Kingdom" explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingdom_%28biology%29#Kingdoms_of_the_Eukaryota) 
The three domains Eubacteria, Archeae, and Eukaryota are less disputed.

Comment: You shoudn't be answering this until the OP has shown some effort to answer his own question.

Comment: I agree in general, in this particular case, however, I shared kind of personal interest